# How to get laptop display brightness

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Currently, I'm using this code to get display brightness:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <physicalmonitorenumerationapi.h>
#include <highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi.h>

int main()
{
    HMONITOR monitor = MonitorFromWindow(NULL, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
    DWORD numPhysicalMonitors;
    if (!GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(monitor, &numPhysicalMonitors))
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get the number of physical monitors.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    PHYSICAL_MONITOR* physicalMonitors = new PHYSICAL_MONITOR[numPhysicalMonitors];
    if (!GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(monitor, numPhysicalMonitors, physicalMonitors))
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get physical monitors.\n";
        delete[] physicalMonitors;
        return 1;
    }

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < numPhysicalMonitors; i++)
    {
        DWORD minimumBrightness, currentBrightness, maximumBrightness;
        if (!GetMonitorBrightness(physicalMonitors[i].hPhysicalMonitor, &minimumBrightness, &currentBrightness, &maximumBrightness))
        {
            std::cerr << "Failed to get monitor brightness.\n";
            delete[] physicalMonitors;
            return 1;
        }

        std::cout << "Monitor " << i + 1 << ":\n"
            << "Minimum Brightness: " << minimumBrightness << "\n"
            << "Current Brightness: " << currentBrightness << "\n"
            << "Maximum Brightness: " << maximumBrightness << "\n";
    }

    delete[] physicalMonitors;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't really know anything about WinAPI unfortunately. All this code was put together from results of searching "Brightness" at [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi/nf-highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi-setmonitorbrightness) and follow links to relevant functions.

Currently, I'm using a Lenovo laptop on AMD chip, with Nvidia dedicated GPU. Display mode is set to "Nvidia GPU only". On Windows 11 too.

Though the monitor capabilities part was deleted, it can't even get monitor capabilities (error code translated to "An error occurred while transmitting data to the device on the I2C bus.")

This code was compiled in Visual Studio 2022 community edition, c++lastest standard for C++, Debug configuration for x64 platform. Linked with user32.lib, gdi32.lib, dxva2.lib.

Windows SDK version 10.0.

(Sorry, I don't know which info is matter so I'm trying to dump as much thing as possible here)

I also tried to change the display mode back to Optimus, no luck. Though the brightness control bar was grayed out in GPU only mode, it still normal under Optimus. And I can still change display brightness in both modes using function keys (Fn+F5/6 for this model)

Since I don't know a thing about WinAPI, please also provide additional information/links to documentations if possible. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I did able to set display brightness through DeviceIoControl though. Just failed to get brightness somehow.

Comment: What is the issue? Does the code fail to compile? Does the code fail to link? Does the code fail during execution? Does it run without errors but exhibit undesired behavior? What are you expecting the code to do, and what do you observe?

Comment: Can you get the information from standard Windows UI? If not, chances are the Windows API won't be able to do it either. In this case, DeviceIoControl is the only way, if you know what IO controls to use.

Comment: @IInspectable the `GetMonitorBrightness` function returns FALSE. I expect the code to print out those 3 values: minimum brightness, current brightness and maximum brightness.

Comment: @SimonMourier I'm not entirely sure what you're talking about. But after some poking around, I can finally make it to read text from a Notepad.exe instance. Like I've said, I'm completely new to this "WinAPI" stuff, and my interest is just getting the display brightness, so my knowledge about other parts is an absolute 0. Can you please be more specific about what I should do? I.e. what "information" should I get?

Comment: notepad? what are you talking about, I don't understand

Comment: @SimonMourier Neither do I understand what you mean (the previous one)?Is there any alternative ways to query the display's brightness? Can you link all relevant functions you know?

Comment: I mean, do you know a way in builtin Windows UI (standard menus, settings, etc. for example here https://i.insider.com/5d5d584bcd978423f7091e63?width=700&format=jpeg&auto=webp) where you see the information you're looking for? If not it means it won't be in the API, only proprietary to vendor.

Comment: @SimonMourier Ah sliders in settings? Yes.

Comment: When the GetMonitorBrightness function returns `FALSE`, you could call `GetLastError` to get extended error information. And you could try to use `GetMonitorCapabilities function` to retrieve the configuration capabilities of a monitor. If the GetMonitorBrightness function is supported, the GetMonitorCapabilities function returns the MC_CAPS_BRIGHTNESS flag.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT I tried GetMonitorCapabilities already. But it also failed (also returns `FALSE`. I did figure out a temporary solution eventually though...

Answer (score 0):

I still can't get the `GetMonitorBrightness` and `SetMonitorBrightness` to work. However, I figured out a temporary solution using `DeviceIoControl`. Though this IHMO is a bit... less clean.

Again, I don't know a single thing about WinAPI before I got into this mess by accident. Don't shout at me please.

```cpp
// Based on the example at learn.microsoft.com aka official documentations...
// Perhaps I could do better here? Anyways I'm happy because it works.
bool SetBrightness(HANDLE h, int brightness)
{
    if (brightness > 100)
        brightness = 100;
    if (brightness < 0)
        brightness = 0;
    DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS DisplayBrightness = {
        .ucDisplayPolicy = DISPLAYPOLICY_BOTH,
        .ucACBrightness = (UCHAR)brightness,
        .ucDCBrightness = (UCHAR)brightness,
    };
    DWORD ret = NULL;
    DWORD nOutBufferSize = sizeof(DisplayBrightness);
    if (!DeviceIoControl(h, IOCTL_VIDEO_SET_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS, (DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS*)&DisplayBrightness, nOutBufferSize, NULL, 0, &ret, NULL))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

And getting stuff back is pretty much the same...

```cpp
bool GetBrightness(HANDLE h, DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS& DisplayBrightness)
{
    DWORD BytesReturned;
    // I thought these comments will help me to not get lost when looking at it in the future
    if (!DeviceIoControl(
        /*hDevice*/ h,
        /*dwIoControlCode*/ IOCTL_VIDEO_QUERY_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS,
        /*lpInBuffer*/ NULL, /*nInBufferSize*/ 0,
        /*lpOutBuffer*/ &DisplayBrightness, /*nOutBufferSize*/ sizeof(DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS),
        /*lpBytesReturned*/ &BytesReturned,
        /*lpOverlapped*/ NULL))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

About the getting `HANDLE`s, uh... by using GUID (`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR` in particular) to open **all** monitor devices (because I don't know how to figure out which one's actually matter, and which isn't)

To accomplish this, I have to also install the Windows Driver Kit (WDK).

A slightly annoying thing is there ought to be a slight delay before getting brightness after setting it. Actually, I'm not sure whether it's a slight delay or you actually have to do something, because by "delay" I mean using `std::cin` to get some input into a dummy variable.

Another question arises after using this approach is `GUID_DEVCLASS_MONITOR` doesn't works. But the `_DEVINTERFACE_` do... So please also address it if you know why. Thank you.

**EDIT 1**:

I figured out why `_DEVCLASS_` doesn't work. The error returned when enum the devices is "No more data available". But I still don't understand why.

Comment: I only have 1 actually monitor (integrated monitor) and the Generic PnP one in devmgmt. So I don't know how it will affect me with more than one monitor, but I think all monitors brightness will change, right?